# One in Ten Query in SQL Server very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

When running a very simple query in SQL Server 2000.

SELECT getDate()

Most queries are sub second, but one query randomally in 10 takes about five seconds.

I am running these queries from SQL Server 2008 Management studio, but it occurs in other clients and on other machines as well, so it is not client specific.

The query is running to a server which is on the same network and there is no significant  load on the server.

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you write a stub utility to execute this 500 times in sets of 10 and say which of the 10 times it took the longest? If it truly is random then it is likely a usage or latency issue.

Comment: We have now done this as suggested, and it appears to be every six queries.    Maybe it is cyclical, but why is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like network issues.  We had the same thing happen when I worked for a large bank.  Due to politics, it was out of our control.

You can do a few things to confirm this, like try running the queries from the server, etc.

Comment: Currently thinking it might be a problem with the network card in the machine.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two things I would suspect without more information right off the bat are network latency and server load.  Do you get this behavior when running the query from the database server machine itself?  Do you get this behavior when running in single-user mode?

Comment: If running it directly from the server machine is fine, then it almost certainly is latency.